# Traceroute: target doesn't acknowledge packet just from a specific host. Traceroutes from other hosts work fine. Ping works fine from all hosts

Tags: linux, windows, networking, soap

So I am a bit puzzled by this. All of this is in a larger corporate network, but all machines are basically on site.

We have one machine (linux) sending SOAP requests to the other machine (windows) and since a few days these requests fail after a certain time. We haven't found any pattern as to which requests fail (doesn't seem to be a particular request).

We tried a traceroute from the requesting machine to the target machine and the target machine doesn't acknowledge the packet (asterisks at the target). A running ping did work and did not drop any packets.

The target machine is a VM on a host hosting many machines.

The problem started after a scheduled restart a few days ago.

Our team is actually only responsible for the application on the target server, but we are invested in helping pinpoint the problem.

Apart from running wireshark on the target server and looking for the traceroute or soap packets, is there any other point of failure where we can investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using domain names (not IP), check that they are resolved properly. ISP dropping the packets would not be an issue since everything is on site.

Ping works, so I assume both machines see each other on the network. But is it should be the sending machine (linux) to send the Ping to be sure that the machine isn't blocked somewhere in the network.

Ping works, but traceroute doesn't, check for possible Firewall issues. Check if its the request not getting to the Windows machine or the reply isn't getting out.

Comment: "If you are using domain names (not IP), check that they are resolved properly."

Yes. Forgot to add that we already did that.Tracing and pinging with just ips produces the same results.

"check for possible Firewall issues."

Thanks, will do.

"Check if its the request not getting to the Windows machine or the reply isn't getting out."

We are hoping that the wireshark capture on both machines will show this. Any reason why it wouldn't?

Comment: Two-way Firewalls could cause this. Prevents a request from getting in and prevents a reply from getting out. You have to open the port for the request get received and allow the server in the firewall rights to respond and use the network to send the reply.

Comment: hi @jarvis we never ended up finding out what was going on. We permanently switched to the test system that was mirrored from the production system and went from there. We recently moved back to the production system and the issues were not found.

Sorry for having no real resolution on this. I'll still mark you as the answer.